# Is it possible to create an object of a class with the name counted?

Tags: android, object

Lets say I have a class Dog and every Time a Button is pressed, I want to make a new Dog with a new name, but I want the object to be counted.

```
class Dog{

private String Name;

public Dog(String Name){

this.Name = Name;
}
```

So, now what is inside the button OnClickListener:

```
// inside Button pressed
{
Dog Dog+i = new Dog(Doggo); //Dog+i is not possible how can I change that?
i++;
}
```

So the object name of the new Dog called Doggo is for example Dog1.
Next time the new Dog is Dog2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah . , you can create as many instance of a class you want .

Comment: But how can I set the Name of new instance with the variable i?
``` Dog+i``` is not possible.

Comment: Nope . My Bad.Not working.

Comment: You may try `loops` to create may obj as you want.

Comment: try `Dog dog = new Dog("Doggo" + i);`

Comment: @Wirling this is like giving the Dog an ID
`class Dog{
int ID;
String Name;

public Dog(int ID, String Name){
this.ID = ID;
this.Name =Name;
}
}
`

Comment: why do you want your variabele to be different each time? Maybe you are trying to solve a problem that can be solved in another way.

Comment: I use a queue and I want to add Objects like:

`Dog mDog = new Dog("Doggo");`
`myQueue.add(mDog);`
`mDog.setName("OtherDoggo");`
`myQueue.add(mDog);`

Comment: But when I read the Queue the Dogs name is 90% "OtherDoggo" and just 10% "Doggo". When i creat a new Object everytime, the Dogs have Different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an incompatible types. It will directly show you compile time error. It can not work using counted name of the object.

Comment: So there is now format to make newDog+i work?
`Dog newDog+i = new Dog(Doggo)`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  Dog dog = new Dog("Dog"+ i); 
  i++;
}
```

Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: No, this would be Doggo1 in my examle, but I look for:
`Dog dog+i = new Dog("Dog")`

Comment: you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

if you looking for to count every single object created from class you can use a static `int` inside of constructor and just `++` it;

```
class Dog{

        private String Name;
        private static int i = 0;
        public Dog(String Name){
         i++;
        this.Name = Name + i;

        }
    public int GetCount(){return i;}
}
```